# Can't add WebViewFragment derived class to FragmentTransaction

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I am using ActionBarSherlock and implementing a tabbed app.  Each tab represents a Fragment that contains nothing but a WebView.  I've got it implemented with my object derived from Fragment.  But when I changed it to WebViewFragment, I can no longer add it to the FragmentTransaction.  I'm wondering if I importing the right things?  Here's the code:

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.webkit.WebViewFragment;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class WebTab1Fragment extends FragmentActivity {
    int mStackLevel = 1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.webtab1_layout);


    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        // Do first time initialization -- add initial fragment.
        MyWebvewFragment newFragment = MyWebviewFragment.newInstance(mStackLevel);
        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.add(R.id.simple_fragment, newFragment).commit();

    } else {
        mStackLevel = savedInstanceState.getInt("level");
    }
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putInt("level", mStackLevel);
}


void addFragmentToStack() {
    mStackLevel++;

    // Instantiate a new fragment.
    MyWebviewFragment newFragment = MyWebviewFragment.newInstance(mStackLevel);

    // Add the fragment to the activity, pushing this transaction
    // on to the back stack.
    FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.simple_fragment, newFragment);
    ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
    ft.addToBackStack(null);
    ft.commit();
}



public static class MyWebviewFragment extends WebViewFragment {
    int mNum;
    private WebView webview = null;
    private ProgressDialog mSpinner = null;
    private static final int DIALOG_PROGRESS = 1;
    private Handler mProgressHandler;
    boolean bFinishFlag = true;

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       mProgressHandler = new Handler() {
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                super.handleMessage(msg);
                if (bFinishFlag == true)
                    mSpinner.dismiss();
                else
                    mProgressHandler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(0, 100);
            }
        };

        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new instance of CountingFragment, providing "num"
     * as an argument.
     */
    static MyWebviewFragment newInstance(int num) {
        MyWebviewFragment f = new MyWebviewFragment();

        // Supply num input as an argument.
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("num", num);
        f.setArguments(args);

        return f;
    }
```

The problem lines are:

```
ft.add(R.id.simple_fragment, newFragment).commit();

 ....

 ft.replace(R.id.simple_fragment, newFragment);
```

I can't figure out why.  MyWebviewFragment extends WebViewFragment which extend Fragment.  FragmentTransaction methods should see MyWebviewFragment as if it were a simple Fragment.  Like I said earlier, could this have something to do with my imports?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> MyWebviewFragment extends WebViewFragment which extend Fragment.

You cannot mix API Level 11 native fragments (`android.app.Fragment`) and Android Support package fragments (`android.support.v4.app.Fragment`). You cannot create an `android.webkit.WebViewFragment` and use it with an `android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity`, because `android.webkit.WebViewFragment` extends `android.app.Fragment`, not `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`.

Either do not use ActionBarSherlock and the Android Support package, by creating an API Level 11+ app, or do not use `WebViewFragment` (or copy it from the source code and refactor it into your project).

Comment: I was afraid of that.  I hope they add WebViewFragment to the Android Support package soon.  It's a big hole for those people wanting to run on all platforms while still using fragments.

Comment: @JustLearningAgain: `WebViewFragment` is [about 100 lines of code](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/webkit/WebViewFragment.java). Copy it into your project, refactoring it into your own package, and alter it to inherit from the `support.v4` edition of `Fragment`. I did this on one project (not yet released, or I'd point you to it), and so far it has been working fine.